# unable to render child template to layout

Tags: flask

I tried to render both `render_template('index.html')` and render_template('layout.html'). only the header and layouts render. the index is not rendering. where is it going wrong?

app.py

```
@app.route('/')
  def index():
  return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

header.html:

```
 {% block header %}
   <div>this is header</div>  
 {% endblock %}
```

Layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>{% block title %} - My Site {% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

   {% include 'header.html' %}


   {% block content %}
     <div> this is the layouts <div>
   {% endblock %}


  </body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
 {% extends 'layout.html' %}

  {% block content %}
   <div>this is index page</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens is that the [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) concept is a bit different. In case, when you extended layout.html inside the index.html file, you would necessarily need to call the header replacement inside of it as well. So the header was not called. Here is an example:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block header %}
<div>this is header</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div>this is index page</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have developed a project that helps you in a series of automatic creations, in case you want to venture out and help me improve it feel at ease: https://github.com/marcosstefani/flute